# IONIC 2 : Touch ID not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

For some reason when i try to use TOUCH ID in IOS 10.2; iPhone 7 simulator i get the following error; I have touch ID enrolled on the simulator; one thing to note when i click my fingerprint button it never prompts me for the fingerprint it just immediately says the error below.

> Feb 7 10:36:32 mymac-MBP App[14690]: Fingerprint or device passcode
>   could not be validated. Status -25300. Feb 7 10:36:32 mymac-MBP
>   App[14690]: ERROR: Error [object Object] Feb 7 10:37:50 mymac-MBP
>   securityd[14639]: found no keychain client entitlements. ta

Here is my code

about.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TouchID } from 'ionic-native';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    console.log('test');



console.log('test');

  }

  verify(){
    TouchID.verifyFingerprint('Scan your fingerprint please')
.then(
  res => console.log('Ok', res),
  err => console.error('Error', err)
);

  }

}
```

about.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      About
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<button ion-button (click)="verify()" block>Fingerprint</button>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.. basically it only works on an actual device and not the emulator for some odd reason. Still couldn't figure out the emulator. Maybe it's a bug?